# How to process array of hashes in a better way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

Below is the array of hashes from the PGResult set.

```
result = [
  {"type" => 1 , "original" => "true",  "count" => "10"},
  {"type" => 1 , "original" => "false",  "count" => "20"},
  {"type" => 2 , "original" => "false",  "count" => "30"},
  {"type" => 2 , "original" => "true",   "count" => "40"},
  {"type" => 3 , "original" => "true",   "count" => "50"},
  {"type" => 3 , "original" => "false",  "count" => "60"}
]
```

I want to process the above array of hashes to the below format. 
total_count = count of original("true") - count of original("false") for each type!

```
[
  {"type" => 1, "total_count" => "-10"},
  {"type" => 2, "total_count" => "10"},
  {"type" => 3, "total_count" => "-10"}
]
```

any hint to process the above array ?

Comment: Your results do not seem to match your description shouldn't type 1 be -10 in this case? (10 - 20)

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

```
result = [
  {"type" => 1 , "original" => "true",   "count" => "10"},
  {"type" => 1 , "original" => "false",  "count" => "20"},
  {"type" => 2 , "original" => "false",  "count" => "30"},
  {"type" => 2 , "original" => "true",   "count" => "40"},
  {"type" => 3 , "original" => "true",   "count" => "50"},
  {"type" => 3 , "original" => "false",  "count" => "60"}
]

# will be used to extract "proper" value - positive or negative
to_value = -> (group) do
  value = group["count"].to_i
  group["original"] == "false" ? -value : value
end

groups = result.group_by { |h| h["type"] }

counts = groups.map do |num, group|
  { "type" => num,
    "total_count" => group.map(&to_value).inject(:+) }
end

p counts
# => [{"type"=>1, "total_count"=>-10}, {"type"=>2, "total_count"=>10}, {"type"=>3, "total_count"=>-10}]
```

Hope that helps!

Thanks for suggestion of change to `lambda` @engineersmnky!

Comment: I like the use of a lambda here but i fell `group["original"] == "false" ? -value : value` is a bit more concise and rubyesque than an early return statement

Comment: @engineersmnky - hey! That's clever! Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Since you are open to suggestions also `each_with_object([])` is the same as `map` only no need for the `ret` object and `inject(0,:+)`  can be `inject(:+)` or `reduce(:+)`

Comment: Of course I am! Always! It's super interesting, that the current solution is that far from what I had in my head in first place! I was afraid, that if there will be an array with items, where `"count"`'s are only `nil`s, the `inject(:+)` would return `nil` (instead of - as I thought - default value of 0). I've just tested and it works like a charm! This is great power of Pair Programming @engineersmnky! Thank you for your input. If I only could share any points added to my solution! I'm more than happy to remove answer I posted (which seems no longer mine) if you post yours! Cheers!

Comment: If I were interested in stealing your answer I certainly would have. I have no desire to accumulate points as they are superficial at best in my opinion. I am more interested in the community, it's users, and the educational purpose of this forum than some inconsequential number that appears next to my name. As for the `nil` issue this was already solved by your usage of `group["count"].to_i` where as even if `group` does not have a `count` element `nil.to_i => 0` and `inject` will use the first value in the collection as the starting value in the event a starting value is not given.

Answer (score 1):

```
 result.group_by {|h| h['type']}.values.map do |h1, h2|
   new_hash = {"type" => h1["type"]}
   new_hash["total_count"] = h1["original"] == "false" ? h1["count"].to_i - h2["count"].to_i : h2["count"].to_i - h1["count"].to_i
   new_hash
 end
 # => [{"type"=>1, "total_count"=>10}, {"type"=>2, "total_count"=>-10}, {"type"=>3, "total_count"=>10}]
```